# How many transactions are executed on the Ethereum network per day, and what are the daily transaction fees?

Tags: transactions, gas, fees

This question was prompted by the Reddit post [Reminder: Ethereum has been doing roughly 40-50k transactions daily for the past 8 months](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5m2x2r/reminder_ethereum_has_been_doing_roughly_4050k/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote the following script to calculate the results:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Find Daily Transactions On The Ethereum Blockchain
# 
# Works on Linux and OS/X. May work on Windows with Cygwin.
#
# Usage:
#   1. Download this script to findDailyTransactions
#   2. `chmod 700 findDailyTransactions`
#   3. Run `geth console` in a window.
#   4. Then run this script `./findDailyTransactions` in a separate window.
#
# History:
#   * Jan 05 2017 - Version 1.0
#
# Enjoy. (c) BokkyPooBah 2016. The MIT licence.
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

OUTPUTFILE=findDailyTransactions.out
TSVFILE=findDailyTransactions.tsv
TSVSUMMARY=findDailyTransactionsSummary.tsv

# geth attach << EOF
geth attach << EOF > $OUTPUTFILE

var blocksPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 / 14;
console.log("Blocks per day: " + blocksPerDay);

// Get extra day
var blocksPerMonth = blocksPerDay * 32;
console.log("Blocks per month: " + blocksPerMonth);

var endBlock = eth.blockNumber;
var startBlock = parseInt(endBlock - blocksPerMonth);

// Testing
// startBlock = parseInt(endBlock - 10);

console.log("Start block: " + startBlock);
console.log("End block: " + endBlock);

var count = {};
var costMap = {};

console.log("Data: Day\tTime\tHash\tGasPrice\tGasUsed\tCost");
for (var i = startBlock; i <= endBlock; i++) {
  var block = eth.getBlock(i, true);
  if (block != null) {
    block.transactions.forEach(function(t) {
      var date = new Date(block.timestamp * 1000);
      var day = date.toJSON().substring(0, 10);
      var time = date.toJSON().substring(11, 19);
      // var key = date.toJSON().substring(11, 16);
      var key = day;
      var tx = eth.getTransaction(t.hash);
      var txR = eth.getTransactionReceipt(t.hash);
      var gasUsed = txR.gasUsed;
      var gasPrice = tx.gasPrice;
      var cost = new BigNumber(gasUsed).mul(gasPrice).div(1e18);
      if (count[key]) {
        count[key]++;
      } else {
        count[key] = 1;
      }
      if (costMap[key]) {
        costMap[key] = costMap[key].plus(cost);
      } else {
        costMap[key] = new BigNumber(cost);
      }
      console.log("Data: " + day + "\t" + time + "\t" + t.hash + "\t" + gasPrice + "\t" + gasUsed + "\t" + cost);
    });
  } 
}

var keys = [];

for (var key in count) {
  keys.push(key);
}

keys.sort();

console.log("Summary: Date\tTxCount\tSumCost");
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var key = keys[i];
  var num = count[key];
  var cost = costMap[key];
  console.log("Summary: " + key + " " + num + " " + cost);
}

EOF

grep "Data:" $OUTPUTFILE | sed "s/Data: //" > $TSVFILE
grep "Summary:" $OUTPUTFILE | sed "s/Summary: //" > $TSVSUMMARY
```

Here are the first few lines of the detailed results:

```
Day     Time    Hash    GasPrice        GasUsed Cost
2016-12-03      15:35:10        0x15a9b8dae315f12a6f0ee915fe98df4360d1862b86a5d5643ae782136572afde      20000000000     30416   0.00060832
2016-12-03      15:35:10        0x1aee9737476e99139d1dbac25248252c04f79e62e69f5ab6d7cf90c3d01e9bd5      20000000000     30416   0.00060832
2016-12-03      15:35:10        0x2f5bb05eab245082449fca28f1cf8179c82bb11e3d3026b782177c2db4a31621      20000000000     30416   0.00060832
2016-12-03      15:35:10        0x475591c2c02482b8c4410b9cb6e21f84311bc93a49b278baf4c9da9dd3ab9940      20000000000     30416   0.00060832
2016-12-03      15:35:10        0xefebae78a289e5e637835418b8b105cccc8add376777099fb2f446003b4760e1      20000000000     30416   0.00060832
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0xd39d3f343a84df8a155eb4e4b1907d2835445b23690b75066c3350ce2508e463      60000000000     21000   0.00126
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0x5b223cafd94bbb55e50e6f25dcda278b806e2f33a59d9b86cf8db5a1cc3037dc      55000000000     65600   0.003608
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0x952e33c725aab06d2f84cf90c3880e177e43f1d1cba3032839e2d20ee54c975d      21000000000     21000   0.000441
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0x2ec12796c790700dbbb678344f1030901f3666406e81b096dd5658f50076562f      20000000000     21000   0.00042
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0x3429d7477ba1953917b270662922e0e33b7ef99c62a8c1e8aacbde1cc781f705      20000000000     21000   0.00042
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0x4f4939bbe3b3764ca343c50d87896aba3daede24e6d0d7019bc10bcd610540fc      20000000000     37744   0.00075488
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0x653b95af57d7d5ea871d628ba42dfe74e92316519cc574108c8127c770e8cf17      20000000000     22900   0.000458
2016-12-03      15:37:28        0x758f5d0ff2e6ba7ff358f6e448c558bb44e84462817471b5f08ba9be28856f1f      20000000000     21000   0.00042
```

Here are the summary results. `SumCost` is the sum of the transaction fees for the day. Ignore the first and last entries as these are statistics for part days:

```
Date    TxCount SumCost
2016-12-03 13652 9.031858962045600786
2016-12-04 39643 26.2590678522622502
2016-12-05 41613 31.260227778687816479
2016-12-06 48200 34.724190362202270091
2016-12-07 41757 34.986830893400990279
2016-12-08 39587 792.488980472847617318
2016-12-09 41444 31.427944831704979055
2016-12-10 40564 29.027316459710687448
2016-12-11 39164 36.802824752362151712
2016-12-12 38741 31.236666299979217642
2016-12-13 44664 30.96445138376004775
2016-12-14 47294 34.886653378922419663
2016-12-15 46102 34.427867607164909959
2016-12-16 43953 30.59438815455709639
2016-12-17 39442 32.801700786191403698
2016-12-18 36640 27.723246559895049134
2016-12-19 45599 36.451357768973606076
2016-12-20 44241 43.901597465334609193
2016-12-21 50793 54.747365402673830874
2016-12-22 55173 38.844405597480919257
2016-12-23 44391 29.67366918963357803
2016-12-24 37757 25.81752534909212622
2016-12-25 36601 24.217901540017729787
2016-12-26 34565 23.120413010232811283
2016-12-27 42370 36.398134576455099831
2016-12-28 43386 31.575304426588826066
2016-12-29 46546 40.700293206458891043
2016-12-30 44561 44.81091076572642845
2016-12-31 41220 28.598800805711720561
2017-01-01 38730 25.262224854177027598
2017-01-02 39652 28.118341055529409329
2017-01-03 45883 40.245343098687603577
2017-01-04 50673 39.504583436605983867
2017-01-05 12948 9.243102890131226982
```

Here are the calculated averages:
[image]

Compare the stats above to Bitcoin at [Cost per Transaction - Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/cost-per-transaction):
[image]

And [Confirmed Transaction Per Day - Blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions):
[image]

---

### Excessively High Fee Transaction

Did you see the odd looking number on 2016-12-08? What happened here?

Sorting the individual transactions by cost, the following transaction showed up as costing 761.62326635721637 Ether ($7,639.08).

From [0xeda3bf566ae21fbc7bbfcb805d73181b0037036d700d57695e28f1e9bfe0d69c](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeda3bf566ae21fbc7bbfcb805d73181b0037036d700d57695e28f1e9bfe0d69c):

[image]

I had to double check the gasPrice in `geth`:

```
> eth.getTransaction("0xeda3bf566ae21fbc7bbfcb805d73181b0037036d700d57695e28f1e9bfe0d69c")
{
  blockHash: "0x9b92631efb5a96157d4bac9ef8b795df2d22ece167f923498d5e226578c00665",
  blockNumber: 2770908,
  from: "0xf0f3589042f8e74b1c060fe9aa8e320c8d907708",
  gas: 21000,
  gasPrice: 36267774588438875,
  hash: "0xeda3bf566ae21fbc7bbfcb805d73181b0037036d700d57695e28f1e9bfe0d69c",
  input: "0x",
  nonce: 0,
  r: "0x251c1c08d8a4a4c98bbb11563cad6f5d9b1535bde692ae7812be84dae5c71cb5",
  s: "0x623dc847eee1911e4f087173075475f3e0ad3ef267c681dc1f72f6ff62aee6ac",
  to: "0x2b62ecf08052e90980d41ba588593e841bee5ecf",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x25",
  value: 350000000000000000000
}
> eth.getTransaction("0xeda3bf566ae21fbc7bbfcb805d73181b0037036d700d57695e28f1e9bfe0d69c").gasPrice/1e18
0.03626777458843887
```

From the [Ethereum GasPrice History - Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/chart/gasprice), you can see the large blip on the chart:
[image]

From block [#2770908](https://etherscan.io/block/2770908), DwarfPool1 collected the mining fees:

[image]

And it seems that DwarfPool refunded the account with the excessive fees in [0x92cde2e39dfc604ede142810736a1fcadce5b925da8d957dcc4e881f34d7c513](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x92cde2e39dfc604ede142810736a1fcadce5b925da8d957dcc4e881f34d7c513):

[image]